# Symfony validation is slow

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to make an object validation in Symfony 6 as described in the documentation.
But it works very slow for some reason. A controller method with validation takes about 400-500ms to finish, when the same method without validation takes about 25-30ms.

The framework configuration is like default, I didn't change anything related to caching or validation.

Why it could be so slow and how to make it faster?
Here is my validation config yaml:

```
file config/validator/validation.yaml

App\Request\BusinessTripSearchRequest:
limit:
  - Type: integer
  - Positive: ~
offset:
  - Type: integer
  - PositiveOrZero: ~
```

Here is the controller method:

```
public function getBusinessTrips(ValidatorInterface $validator, Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $businessTripSearchRequest = new BusinessTripSearchRequest($request->query->all());
    $violations = $validator->validate($businessTripSearchRequest);
    
    return new JsonResponse([
        'result' => true,
    ]);
}
```

BusinessTripSearchRequest class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Request;

class BusinessTripSearchRequest
{
    private ?int $limit = null;
    private ?int $offset = null;

    public function __construct(array $data)
    {
        if (isset($data['limit'])) {
            $this->limit = $data['limit'];
        }

        if (isset($data['offset'])) {
            $this->offset = $data['offset'];
        }
    }

    public function getLimit(): ?int
    {
        return $this->limit;
    }

    public function getOffset(): ?int
    {
        return $this->offset;
    }
}
```

So if I comment out this line it gets much faster:

```
$violations = $validator->validate($businessTripSearchRequest);
```

Comment: I think your code is right to reduce time i think there is two ways either apply cache for validation (so once the cache is warmed it's ok), or apply groups so the check only is only applied on a specific group instead of muliple validation based on class name and Default group

Comment: I don't know how to enable validation cache that is the main problem. As well as don't know how to apply a group. Can you share some links preferably about validation cache?

Comment: Sure for validation cache https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache.html and i beleive the best way is https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/groups.html (use a specific validation group)

Comment: Applying groups doesn't make any effect. Can you write a short example how to apply cache to a validator?  I don't think to should be something like `$cache->save($validator);` or `$cache->save($validator->validate($businessTripSearchRequest));` it won't work as expected.

Comment: If you apply the cache the first response will still be 400ms it's when reloaded it's will be faster

Comment: I mean if I apply cache like this `$cache->save($validator->validate($businessTripSearchRequest));` it will not work because `$businessTripSearchRequest` object has different data on each request. Thus I should create cache for each individual request, but there is no reason to do that, because requests are not repeatable and if I cache one request validation it will work slow on next requests.

Comment: You can validate $request->query->all(); wich is an array that does not change instead of the businessTripSearchRequest

Comment: Looks like you gave me an idea. If I create the validator by myself instead of injecting in as an argument, like this `$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->setMappingCache(new FilesystemAdapter())->getValidator();` it gets really fast. Tanks!